# Как отменить filter: blur(2px) для дочернего элемента?

Tags: filter, blur

```
<article>
 <section class="menu">
  <div>Блок с меню, прижатый вниз</div>
 </section>
<section class="bg">
 <h1>Обычный заголовок со стилями</h1>
</section>
</article>
```

При наведении на меню "menu", добавлены стили к классу "bg" filter: blur(2px), transform: scale(1.02);.
При этом дочерний h1, также подхватывает стили родителя, что логично.
Вопрос, как отменить применение этих стилей к дочернему элементу?

Comment: Никак, только разбить их на разные. В вашем случае все, что есть в `.bg` я вынес бы в `.bg:before`

Comment: Прикрепите так же работающий код в вопрос, чтобы можно было наглядно увидеть

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае помогают селекторы `*` (взять все дочерние элементы) и `not(h1)` (убрать из выборки h1):

```css
.bg *:not(h1){
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scale(1.02);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section class="menu">
    <div>Блок с меню, прижатый вниз</div>
  </section>
  <section class="bg">
    <h1>Обычный заголовок со стилями</h1>
    <h2>Обычный заголовок со стилями</h2>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: а сам `.bg` при этом не размыт, судя из названия класса думаю это обязательно

Comment: Возможно. Я ответил по конкретному примеру. Если надо bg весь размыть, можно сделать его дочерним для какого-то другого и такую же манипуляцию провести с этим другим

Comment: Полный код https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEGbqB
Селектор * не помог.